# Reference a local file in my phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to reference a local html file in my phonegap android app. I am seeing where something like www/myapp_name/somefile.html does not work, is there a away to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add the www. If you structure is as follow

```
/myprojectname/www/index.html
/myprojectname/www/contact.html
```

And you wish to make a link from index.html to contact.html you can juse use

```
<a href="contact.html">contact.html</a>
```

Just use the relative path. Don't add a `/` up front.